# Replace Carriage Return (CR) and Carriage Return and Line Feed (CRLF) python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I import a `.csv` file that looks like:

[image]

by using the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658055/how-can-i-remove-carriage-return-from-a-text-file-with-python/42442131):

```
filetoread = 'G:/input.csv'
filetowrite = 'G:/output.csv'

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658055/how-can-i-remove-carriage-return-from-a-text-file-with-python/42442131

with open(filetoread, "rb") as inf:
    with open(filetowrite, "wb") as fixed:
        for line in inf:
            # line = line.replace('\r\r\n', 'r\n')
            fixed.write(line)
            print(line)
```

Which give the output:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbfHeader1;Header2;Header3;Header4;Header5;Header6;Header7;Header8;Header9;Header10;Header11;Header12\r\n'
b';;;1999-01-01;;;01;;;;;;\r\n'
b';;;2000-01-01;;;12;;"NY123456789\r\r\n'
b'";chapter;2020-01-01 00:00:00;PE\r\n'
b';;;2020-01-01;;;45;;"NY123456789\r\r\n'
b'";chapter;1900-01-01 00:00:00;PE\r\n'
b';;;1999-01-01;;;98;;;;;;\r\n'
```

I have issues to replace `\r\r\n` to `\r\n` which I guess I need to do to get my desired output.
The error I get when I try to replace the `\r\r\n` is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:/till_format_2.py", line 10, in <module>
    line = line.replace('\r\r\n', 'r\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

My desired output:

[image]

What do I need to add or change to the code to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, supply a `bytes` object.

```
line = line.replace(b'\r\r\n', b'\r\n')
```

---

To get the desired output

```
line = line.replace(b'\r\r\n', b'')
```