# Python - remove spaces on the right side

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've text files in folder, but files have data as below:

[image]

I don't know how I can remove spaces from right side between CRLF. These are spaces:

```
33/22-BBB<there is a space to remove>CRLF
```

```
import os

root_path = "C:/Users/adm/Desktop/test"

if os.path.exists(root_path):
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(root_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root_path, name)):
            files.append(os.path.join(root_path, name))

    for ii in files:
        with open(ii) as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.rstrip()
                if line:
                    print(line)
        file.close()
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove carriage return from a text file with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658055/how-can-i-remove-carriage-return-from-a-text-file-with-python)

Comment: FYI : `file.close()` statement is useless, `with` statement already take care of closing it when you leave the code block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I trim whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-do-i-trim-whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

Those are control characters, change your `open()` command to:

```py
with open(ii, "r", errors = "ignore") as file:
```

or

```py
# Bytes mode
with open(ii, "rb") as file:
```

or

```py
# '\r\n' is CR LF. See link at bottom
with open(ii, "r", newline='\r\n') as file:
```

> [Control characters in ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII)

Comment: there is a space between the CRLF character and the end of the expression which I can't get rid of

Comment: Maybe, you could then change the `newline` to `newline='\r \n'`. Either way, it's worth copy pasting into [here](https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer) and updating the question

Comment: @danio900409 use `x.strip()` to remove trailing spaces

Answer (score -2):

If it is the CRLF characters you would like to remove from each string, you could use `line.replace('CRLF', '')`.

Comment: I highly doubt those are standard CRLF characters you can handle with this replace.

Comment: there is a space between the CRLF character and the end of the expression which I can't get rid of