# How to remove newline from string (result from file.readline) in python?

Tags: python, file

I need to read a line from file and strip new line character(s) from the end of the line.
The end line can be either LF or CR LF, so I can't just strip the last character.
Is there any simple way to do it in python? Or the only way to do it is to check with which ending string ends and strip 1 or 2 characters for LF or CR LF respectively?

Comment: I would suggest sharing your attempt on which we can work on

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658055/how-can-i-remove-carriage-return-from-a-text-file-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `string.replace()` function which will replace anything it finds in the function. You can remove both using the following code where `string` is your string variable

```
string.replace('\r', '')
string.replace('\n', '')
```

You could also put this into a function which takes `string` as an argument and returns it.

```
def removeCRLF(string:str)->str: # removeCRLF with type hinting [variable]:[type] and -> [return type]
 return string.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')
```

This would make calling it on your string similar to this:

```
newString = removeCRLF(oldString)
```

Comment: This should be unnecessary; modern Python normalizes all line endings to just `\n` unless you go out of your way to avoid that.

Comment: There is really no need to reimplement `str. rstrip()`.

Comment: @tripleee You could just remove the parts that remove `\r` if you're completely certain your file has normalized line endings like you said.